# prevent function running multiple times at once

Tags: swift

I have a function, that appends text to a file and sends it to the server. Now, this function might be called multiple times at the same time. What is the best way to make sure it completes one call before running the next one?

```
func write(_ text:String) {
    text.appendLineToURL(fileURL: self.path)
    sendLog(text)
}

func sendLog(_ text:String) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Look into async await and actors

Comment: i did, but i don't understand how this helps me, if i want to call `write` from different places, how do i tell it to wait, until the running one is finished?

Comment: If all your code conforms to the new concurrency (adding `async` to a function is not conforming) all your calls will be in order and an `actor` will make sure of it. But it has to be done properly. nobody here can help you more because we don't have a reproducible example and we don't even know where the work become async.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, i think i got it working.
What i do now is create a serial `DispatchQueue` for my singleton and extract the method to a private method, which i then call in my public method using the serial queue

```
private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "logger")

func send(_ text:String) {     
    queue.async {
        self.sendImpl(text)
    }
}

private func writeImpl(_ text:String) {
    text.appendLineToURL(fileURL: self.path)
    sendLog(text)
}
```

Comment: The second method writeImpl is pointless and just increases the danger of breaking the contract (because you can still access it outside your serial queue).